# Java binary not picking up resources from the specified class path

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I am trying to load a text file as InputStream, but the txt file is never picked up and the input stream value is always **null**. I don't know why this is happening and I would like to request assistance.

```
nohup java  -jar crawler-jar-2014.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -classpath /home/nbsxlwa/crawler/resources/common-conf:/home/nbsxlwa/crawler/resources/dotcom-conf:./plugins/*:./lib/* &
```

The txt file is located in `/home/nbsxlwa/crawler/resources/dotcom-conf` directory. I can confirm that the file does exist, so I don't know why the file is not being picked up. The setup is given below:

1. `System.getEnvironment("java.class.path")

   returns the following
           value `crawler-jar-2014.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2. The code blocks are trying to create an input stream out of text.

> ```
>  String fileRules = conf.get(URLFILTER_REGEX_FILE);
> System.out.println("file rules = " + fileRules);
>
> // Pass the file as a resource in classpath.
> // return conf.getConfResourceAsReader(fileRules);
> // Pass the file as a resource in classpath.
> InputStream is = RegexURLFilter.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + fileRules);
>
> System.out.println("Inputstream is = " + is);
> System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileRules));
> ```

The output to  the above snippet is

```
file rules = regex-urlfilter.txt
Inputstream is = null
null
```

3. I tried adding classpath folders to the classpath MANIFEST.MF file. MANIFEST.MF contains the following entries, but the output still returned **null**.

> Class-Path: resources/common-conf resources/dotcom-conf
>   resources/olb-conf lib/gora-cassandra-0.3.jar ** OTHER JARS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the [`java` man page entry for `-jar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> **When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

So your other classpath entries are ignored. You'll have to use the plain old `java` command, specifying a class with a main method and including your `.jar` in the classpath.

The relative paths you've specified in the MANIFEST are relative to the JAR itself or are complete URLs.

Comment: I have created the folder with classes. That worked.